# How to send Image from Firebase Database ?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I have created Database in firebase and from there I am getting an Url of Image. So  I want to share that image but below code  did not work for me... Please Help me.

```
String pictureFile = mdata.get(holder.getHolderPosition).getImage();
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//Send to Whattssap
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
//Even you can add text to the image
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, picture_text);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

try {
    startActivity(shareIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to upload an image to firebase?

Comment: probably you have to download an Image first then you can share using it's URI

Comment: No I want that Image from Firebase Database and want to make sharable but its not happening...

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your image in **Firebase Storage**. here's the link [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)